How to calculate a running total active customers for each month with two date columns (start_date and cancel_date)?
I have a SQL database. In there we keep track of all our customers. There is a column that tracks when they started (start_date) and when they canceled (cancel_date).
For each month, I want to calculate how many clients we had. So in January 2019 it would be all start_date <= January 2019 minus all cancel_dates <= January 2019.
I don't know how to write the SQL statement needed.

Which SQL database?  They aren't all the same.

It would be nice to, at least, provide your initial attempt.

But in general, it's going to be something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x WHERE x.start_date <= '2019-01-01' AND (x.cancel_date IS NULL OR x.cancel_date >= '2019-01-31').  Right?

If a customer cancels on Jan 1, 2019 should they get counted for Jan? Your cancel_dates <= January 2019 suggests yes.

You write "for each month". What should this mean? Which is the first month, which the last and where do you get this information from?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Don't forget to include your current query attempt. And also add a tag for the dbms used - when it comes to date/time functionality, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

@rankRascal Did you find out which SQL database type you are using yet?

To solve this issue I would start by generating a calendar table. Then I can join on customers and count them based on the calendar date between the start and cancel dates. I assume you have a SQL-Server version between 2005 and 2019.
I am using suggestions from:
Jamiec Months between two dates
and
MatBailie Getting only Month and Year from SQL DATE
declare @start DATE = '2019-01-01'
declare @end DATE = '2020-01-01'

;with months (date)
AS
(
    SELECT @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,date)
    from months
    where DATEADD(month,1,date)<=@end
), YearMonth as
(
select date, year(date) as [Year], Datename(month,date) as [Month] 
from months
)
SELECT [Year], [Month], Count(*) as CustomerCount
FROM Customers C
  INNER JOIN YearMonth Y on 
  --Customer had any business on this YearMonth
  Y.date
  BETWEEN 
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, C.Start_date), 0)  
  AND
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, C.Cancel_Date), 0)   

GROUP BY [Year], [Month]
ORDER BY min(Y.date)

SQL Server fiddle
MySQL fiddle



Year
Month
CustomerCount




2019
January
2


2019
February
4


2019
March
3


2019
April
5


2019
May
5


2019
June
4


2019
July
2


2019
August
1




Better wait OP to clarify their unclear question rather than taking assumptions. If they don't use the RDBMS you talk about, your answer won't help them.
